# no internet access or no network access when i share My internet

Tags: networking

I have the problem of no internet access or no network access when I share My internet

- I have two network (wireless) card
- I reserve internet from First card and share from another
- I try use many programs like connectify, mypublicwifi
- All of them have same problem
- No internet access or no network access
- Now I use Zapya (some times) it works

How I can fix this?

Network And sharing center:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/WNpUo4N.jpg]

The access point ( Zapya )

[image: http://i.imgur.com/wP43Oay.jpg]

Comment: You should be able to use Windows ICS (Internet Connection Sharing) to share your wireless card to the other...??

Comment: how i can use Windows ICS ??

Comment: look i already share My Connection 
http://i.imgur.com/qTsDRx7.png

Comment: Can you edit your question as I assumed you had two wireless card that you were trying to share... your second image shows "Local Area Connection 4" - this will typically be an ethernet connection. Are you trying to share your Ethernet connection over your wifi?

Comment: ya i hava tow wireless card

http://i.imgur.com/ciMWhDk.png

but Zapya make "Local Area Connection 4

Comment: and look this image when work :(

http://i.imgur.com/197d7GZ.png

Comment: I'm not a fan of the software sharing applications because they install virtual adapters that then confuse things more... you should be able to go to the properties of the card you want to share and select the other wireless card... ICS should then do all the hard work...

Comment: me too but what can i do i need re-share my WiFi because The router signal so poor

Comment: Just follow the standard ICS instructions and you should be able to share your wifi to your other wifi...

Comment: thank for help
but in this image http://i.imgur.com/qTsDRx7.png
make ICS